# How resolve a Restangular resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, restangular, resolve

I'm new using Restangular and I don't understand how resolve the promises using my own service. I' ve been trying to return the `customGET` method but in my controller the response it's a object that contain all the methods of the restangular resource, so i don't understand how get the response data. I inspect the network activity and the data it's retrieved.

My Service

```
  angular
    .module('Form29')
    .service('Form29Service', Service);

  Service.$inject = ['Restangular'];

  function Service(Restangular) {

    this.serviceResource = Restangular.all('forms');
    this.getForm29 = getForm29;

    function getForm29(_month, _year, _type) {
      var params = {
        rut: '76195496',
        month: _month,
        year: _year,
        type: _type
      };
      return this.serviceResource.customGET('',params);
    }
  }
```

My Controller

```
angular
    .module('Form29')
    .controller('Form29Controller', Controller);

  Controller.$inject = ['Form29Service'];

  function Controller(Form29Service) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.submitForm = submitForm;

    function submitForm(month, year, type){
      Form29Service.getForm29(month, year, type).then(showForm);
    }
    function showForm(response){
      console.log(response);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Did you try to replace return this.serviceResource.customGET('',params); by this.serviceResource.get(params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue that that you try to make `customGet` with empty path, in that case you can easily do simple `get(queryParams)` that will return promise for you.